# libgdx - find coordinates of the upper edge of a sprite?

Tags: android, libgdx, coordinates, sprite

I need to find the top point of a sprite , or its coordinates .

I'm basically doing a game where the user can move and rotate the sprite .
This sprite is an arrow , and when it stops rotating I have to find the coordinates for it to proceed in the direction of the arrow .
I thought to derive a vector between the point of origin and the top edge of the sprite , which corresponds to the tip of the arrow .
And ' possible to add an anchor point to point over orirgine ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer a different question, because your question is based on the wrong assumptions.  Calculating the direction between the origin of the sprite and the top of the sprite is a bad idea.  It's needlessly complicated.

What you need, to get the result you want, is some simple trigonometry.  Basically, you're trying to take linear (x,y) movement and transform it into any arbitrary direction.

I won't give you a big complicated explanation of why this works, but what you're looking for is two trig functions built into the Math java module: Sin and Cos.  Assuming you're rotating the sprite already, and you have access to its angle of rotation (probably just sprite.getRotation()), do this:

```
setX(getX() + (Math.sin(Math.toDegrees(myAngle)) * speed))
setY(getY() + (Math.cos(Math.toDegrees(myAngle)) * speed))
```

If you're using Box2D to move the entity, then just call applyLinearImpulse or applyForce where the x and y arguments are the equations inside of setX() and setY() respectively.

In this case, myAngle should be updated, per frame, to store the current angle of the sprite.  I can't remember off hand if this will be in radians or degrees by default, but if it's already in degrees then you don't need to pass it through Math.toDegrees() obviously, and doing so will give you weird results.  Speed is the speed, in pixels, per frame that you want the entity to move.

The over-long explanation:  Think of what you're trying to do as moving an object from the center of a theoretical circle, to some point on that circle based on the direction that object is pointing.  The radius of this hypothetical circle is the "speed" with which the object will move.  So to find the point on a circle, from the origin of the circle, based just on the direction and the origin, you use trigonometry.

The sine of any angle will be between 0 and 1 (for 0 and 90 degrees), but it scales appropriately so that the bigger the angle gets, the slower the number increases (relating to the arc of the circle, so for instance if an object was moving in a circle and you traced just the x coordinates of its movement it would look like a pendulum -- see this: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/Circle_cos_sin.gif).

Cosine is just the opposite of sine, practically speaking, so it gets smaller as you approach 90 degrees.  Since the highest value either of these numbers has is 1, you can just multiply them by the radius, and given that they're inverse of each other, they'll supply the point on the circle.

I don't know if that made sense, I've never been good at explaining things like this.